# Why is creating a JAXB context taking so long?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a project where I create several different XML parsers. In each case, I start with an XSD, use JAXB to generate the annotated classes and have some simple boiler-plate to parse an XML stream, similar to:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextClasses);
Unmarshaller parser = context.createUnmarshaller();
Object object = parser.unmarshal(stream);
```

`contextClasses` has the type `Class[]` and contains the class corresponding to the root XML tag and, in some cases, the `ObjectFactory` class as well.

To date that has worked very well. I am now adding a new parser for Oracle's Agile XML based on their [XSD](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2015/09/aXML.xsd). This is not a particularly complex XSD. However, the resulting JABX-generated classes number over 350 and come in at 620K LOC. So there's a lot of generated code. Certainly more than any of my other parsers. The next most complex XSD results in 130+ classes.

For this parser, I only pass in the root tag `AgileData` to the line:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextClasses);
```

and it takes well over a minute to complete this line at runtime. The CPU spikes to 30-40% for the duration. This compares unfavourably to all my other parsers, where this line completes in the proverbial split second.

So, why does this line take so long to complete? (When I review the code, it appears to simply read and load classes and properties, so I'm guessing it's a function of the amount of generated code.)

More importantly, is there anything I can do to make it run much faster, ie. in a similar time to my other parsers?

Comment: Over a minute is a bit too much. I'd check it with a profiler. I work a lot with JAXB, often with [many schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas), but even in the worst case this is normally a few seconds.

Comment: I agree it's definitely too long. The CPU spikes to 30-40% for the whole time too. I'll see if I can profile it.

Comment: I tried the XSD you reference. Creating a context takes ~7-8s, so something is probably fishy with your environment.

Comment: @dave It might make sense for you to share an MCVE projects on GitHub or similar. Ping me when you have it, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @forty-two How did you create your generated classes? Which JAXB compiler? Any specific options? Thanks

Comment: Oracle java 8, xjc without any options: xjc aXML.xsd